# PostgreSQL: Secure LDAP (LDAPS) to AD with LDAPTLS and LDAPSCHEME not working

Tags: postgresql, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to establish secure LDAP (LDAPS) connection for postgresql.

Currently, LDAP authentication method is established and working.

dockerized PostgreSQL v.14

LDAP connection to Active Directory. AD is setup by IT dept

I tried several options like LDAPTLS and LDAPSCHEME but nothing working.

**LDAPTLS:**

modified pg_hba.conf file by adding following rule

`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=test.ldapserver.com ldapport=389 ldaptls=1 ldapbasedn="DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbinddn="CN=test-user,OU=dept,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd="ldappassword" ldapsearchfilter="(&(memberOf=CN=subgroup,OU=dept,OU=special,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com)(cn=$username))"`

IT dept provided only root-ca and sub-ca certificates. Server.key and server.crt not provided.

adding the root-ca cert and modified the postgresql.conf

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/root-ca.crt'
```

`FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "server.crt": No such file or directory`

After I commented the **ssl** and **ssl_ca_file** then the server starts but throw error

```
LOG:  could not start LDAP TLS session: Connect error
DETAIL:  LDAP diagnostics: (unknown error code)
FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "user"
```

How to get the server.key and server.crt if root-ca.crt is provided?

**LDAPSCHEME:**

updated pg_hba.conf file as following

`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=test.ldapserver.com ldapscheme=ldaps ldapbasedn="DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbinddn="CN=test-user,OU=dept,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd="ldappassword" ldapsearchfilter="(&(memberOf=CN=subgroup,OU=dept,OU=special,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com)(cn=$username))"`

```
LOG:  could not perform initial LDAP bind for ldapbinddn="CN=test-user,OU=dept,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" on server "test.ldapserver.com": Can't contact LDAP server
DETAIL:  LDAP diagnostics: (unknown error code)
FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "user"
```

Also added **ldapport=636** and **ldaptls=0**, but the error remain the same.

What is missing here? Because LDAP can bind without adding ldapscheme

I also tried with **ldapurl**, but here seems the url doesn't work correctly

`host   all    all  0.0.0.0/0   ldap ldapscheme=ldaps ldapurl="ldaps://test.ldapserver.com:636/DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com?sub?memberOf=CN=subgroup,OU=dept,OU=special,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbinddn="CN=test-user,OU=dept,DC=test,DC=ldapserver,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd="ldappassword`

Is this the correct way to use ldapurl?

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the use of SSL to secure communication between the client and the PostgreSQL server, and the use of SSL to secure communication between the PostgreSQL server and the LDAP server.  All those setting you mention (server.key, server.crt, ssl, ssl_ca_file) are for the first of those, not the second.

For the second topic, those certs are not configured through PostgreSQL as far as I know. PostgreSQL just outsources that to whatever your LDAP library is, and it would be configured through that package.  Like, for example, /etc/ldap/ldap.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually i am also trying for the second topic. but I could not locate the /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file. Is it in the postgresql? because I can't modify the ldap conf file as I am only provided with the read access to AD.

Comment: The name of the file will depend on your OS and flavor ('/etc/ldap/ldap.conf' is the name used on my Ubuntu Linux for OpenLDAP library).  This is the config for the LDAP client, not for the AD server.  You would probably need to be an admin for the local computer to change it, but not necessarily an admin for the AD server.

Comment: it was a great hint. I had to add TLS_REQCERT never in /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file and now it is working. Thanks alot